# Possibility/impossibility of algebraic sum?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-curves, rational-functions, transcendental-functions

Suppose $ y = g(x_1) - g(x_2)$ on $[a,b],$ and there exists a smooth function $h$ over $[a,b] $ such that $h(y) = \frac{x_2}{x_1}.$

Then, does there exist a set of non-trivial functions $A$ algebraic in $y,f(y)$ such that $g(x_1) +A(y,h(y)) = -g(x_2) + A(y,h(y))$?

For instance I could take someting like $y-\frac{g(x_2)+g(x_1)}{g(x_1)}$ or $(g(x_1)-g(x_2))^2 - \frac{g(x_2)^2}{g(x_1)^2}$ or etc, but it doesn't seem any such combination yields the desired result, and because of that, I don't know if it is impossible. Assessing the possibility could require more abstract properties.

Comment: There can be no such function $h$ (smooth or not) since $x_2/x_1$ is not well-defined as a function of $x_1 - x_2$. e.g., if $x_1 = 2, x_2 = 1$, then $y = 1$ and $x_2 / x_1 = 1/2$, while if $x_1 = 3, x_2 = 2$ then $y$ is still $1$ but $x_2 / x_1 = 2/3$.

Comment: $x_1$ and $x_2$ didn't have to be numbers, would it help if I said $g(x_1) - g(x_2)$?

Comment: Okay, then you could take $g(x) = \log x$.  Then $h$ is well defined: $h(y) = e^{-y}$.  Not sure if there are other non-trivial examples (other than changing the base etc). It's unclear what you mean by "on $[a,b]$" since $y$ is a function of two variables.  What is the domain?

Comment: You are correct that one specific example is $y = \log(x_1) - \log(x_2)$ with $h=e^{-y}$. $[a,b]$ is meant to accommodate functions such as a logarithm which are not smooth over all real numbers but that are smooth over at least some domain. If similar properties applied to other sets of functions (it doesn't matter if they can be explicitly written down like a logarithm and exponential), in this case more generalized, then how could a similar result as in the logarithm case be achieved?

Comment: hmm, doesn't say I have enough for a bounty.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353583/possibility-impossibility-of-algebraic-sum without notice to either site, an abuse of these sites.

Comment: Variant of the deleted question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3559151/is-there-an-algebraic-function-that-will-make-a-difference-symmetric

Comment: Also of the deleted question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3558743/can-rational-functions-isolate-terms

Comment: Can you point to where it says in any rules that I'm obligated to give notice to the math site whenever I want to post something? And you also understand that if people weren't allowed to delete questions, then stackexchange would never have provided that option in the first place?

Comment: Post to MO now deleted.